# Google historical prices on Yahoo Finance before split?

Tags: historical-data, yahoo, adjusted, google, split

I recently noticed that the price history for Google (GOOG) on Yahoo Finance only goes back to when the stock split. For a while I thought they just hadn't gotten around to adjusting the close prices for the split, but it still hasn't been "fixed".

Just wondering if this is normal for Yahoo Finance when a stock splits or not? If so, when might the historical price data from before the split to come back? I use Yahoo data for some of my backtesting, and while I don't necessarily need the Google data, it would be nice to have the entire price history back up and running for purposes of data purity and completeness, so that if I run a backtest on the S&P 500, I don't have holes like that.

If this just normal and temporary, that's fine, but if not I'd like to know in case I should invest some time in finding and writing web scraping algos for another source for daily stock data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stock was split into two share classes, the series that you might be looking for is under the ticker GOOGL.